# Inserir usuarios em banco de dados diferentes

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

tenho dois Banco de dados. Banco de dados A, e Banco de Dados B. O usuário faz o seu cadastro no sistema do banco dados A. Quero criar um gatilho para na mesma hora, esse cadastro também ir para o banco de dados B, para ele ter acesso ao outro sistema, com os mesmo dados. É possível?

Comment: Você quer fazer isso no nível da aplicação ou do banco de dados? É possível das duas maneiras, dependendo dos bancos.

Comment: Você teria como me explicar como funcionaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso você usa uma transaction para garantir que os dados vão ser inseridos nos dois bancos. A inserção vai ser feita uma vez em cada um. Em MySQL fica assim:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO badatabaseA.users (username, password)
    VALUES('test', 'test');
INSERT INTO badatabaseB.users (username, password) 
    VALUES('test','test');
COMMIT;
```

Como estamos usando uma transaction, se ocorrer um problema na inserção dos dados em qualquer uma das tabelas ele vai voltar (rollback) toda a operação.

Comment: Mas dessa forma, uilizando transaction é automatizado? Pq teria que ser algo assim: Toda vez que for inserido um usuario no banco de dados A, automaticamente esse usuario sera inserido no banco de dados B. Para ele ter acesso aos dois sistemas

Comment: Dessa maneira ele vai inserir nos dois ou em nenhum. De repente o que você procura é um trigger que copia quando salva?

Comment: Quero algo que quando a pessoa cadastre no sistema do banco de dados A, automaticamente esse registro vai para o  banco de dados do outro sistema. Com transaction seria manual né?

Comment: Não sei como tá teu inglês, mas seria algo mais no sentido dessa pergunta? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/create-a-trigger-to-update-table-data-on-another-servers-database

Comment: Com transaction ele faz o insert nas duas, não copia de uma para a outra.

Comment: Vou dar uma lida no artigo, e ver se transaction me atende. Mas você já me ajudou dms!! Obrigado!